# update MongoDB by using Express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello guys I am stuck in updating my MongoDB. I've tried many ways to build that function but every time it returns with an error.

this is my last way I've tried which also doesn't work.

So here is my router where everything works fine apart of PUT method

```
// Auth Routes
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
router.route('/auth/signup')
  .post(AuthenticationController.signup);
router.route('/auth/signin')
  .post([requireLogin, AuthenticationController.signin])
router.route('/users/:user_id/data')
  .get(requireAuth, AuthenticationController.index);
router.route('/users/:user_id/data')
  .put(requireAuth, AuthenticationController.update);
```

here is my update function which doesn't seem to work

```
// Update user data
exports.update = function (req, res, next) {
  user.update(conditions, req.body)
  .then(data => {
    if (!data) {return res.status(404).end(); }
    return res.status(200).json(data)
  })
  .catch(err => next(err));
  // res.json({ data: req.user });
}
```

And my user schema

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  userData: [{
    role: {
      type: String
    },
    dob: {
      type: String
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String
    },
    phone: {
      type: Number
    },
    address: [{
      number: { type: String },
      street: { type: String },
      city: { tyle: String },
      postcode: { type: String }
    }],
  }],

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;
  if (user.isNew || user.isModified('password')) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
      if (err) { return next(err) }
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Comment: How You attach Your schema to mongoose ?

Comment: @num8er see my edit please I guess this is what you are asking for

Comment: no, in mongoose You create a mongoose object that has method: `.model` that takes schema and returns model to use. So I see that You've attached it. But I cannot see how You've got `mongoose` object

Comment: @num8er yeah sorry I've just added the line now

Comment: I cannot see how You've got mongoose object. if it's `const mongoose = require('mongoose'); mongoose.mode('user', userSchema);` so it will not work.

Comment: ok, let me write an example. You'll just use it. ok?

Comment: @num8er Ok, the thing is that everything is working like posting getting and deleting but not updating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171356/discussion-between-num8er-and-markus-hayner).